# How to edit gallery arrows in wordpress theme loom?

Tags: wordpress

I am using the wordpress theme loom for a portfolio site where I have galleries for each separate project.  There are two sets of arrows on each gallery; one to move you to the next image in that project and one to move you to the next project gallery.  The arrows on the gallery to move you to the next image are visible only when hovered on.  I would like to make them always visible but cannot figure out where in wordpress to edit this function.

Comment: Do you have any examples of this currently happening within the function. Your best option would be to go back to the theme developer as they will know better than anyone guessing here.

Comment: The "next" arrows are on a hover state and I just want them to be visible at all times. I didn't want to go to the developer if it was a simple wordpress setting that I cannot find but someone on here knew already. But I will go to the developer if it's not.

Comment: Do you have a url so we can see what your exactly on about. Unless someone owns or has installed the theme in the same way you have, then we wont be able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to style.css or if the theme settings has a dedicated place for custom styles.

```
.owl-custom-nav {
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```